# Using query URL in the form

Tags: javascript, object

I am practicing on how to query url. But i could not get my expected output. Here is my code:

Form 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Save Value</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="display.html" method="get">
<label> 
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Form 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function queryVar(variable) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < vars.lenght; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" readonly="readonly" />
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
var firstName = document.getElementById("name").value;
firstName = location.search.substring(1);
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So when i clicked submit button it will go to form 2 and will display the value that i typed in the form 1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: So what *did* happen? An error? the wrong value?

Comment: `lenght` is misspelled, in `for (i = 0; i < vars.lenght; i++) {`.

Comment: the problem is when i typed in the field and click submit, it still go the form 2 but display nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution for what you exactly wanted to do.

**Form 1**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Save Value</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="display.html" method="get">
<label> 
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form 2**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Display</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function queryVar(variable) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" readonly="readonly" />
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("name").value = queryVar("name");
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function queryVar(variable) {
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < vars.lenght; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">
<label>
First Name:
<input name="name" size="20" maxlength="25" type="text" id="name" readonly="readonly" />
</label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("name").value=location.search.substring(1);
</script>
```

1. remove the duplicated opening tag for first script
2. you forgot to assign the data to your field, I did (also put the second script outside of form)

Answer (score 0):

Submitted form data (when using post) goes in the HTTP Request headers and are not accessible for JavaScript. You need to use a code preprocessor (like PHP) or pass the data to the url hash which would be extremely rare.

When using get, you should still use a preprocessor and not javascript for doing that. That was the actual purpose when introducing the "get" request type.

Comment: The OP used the GET method, which is accessible through JavaScript `location.search` property, as is used in the question.

Comment: Why not use JavaScript to get query string values?

Comment: I am not saying you cant, I'm saying that wasn't the purpose. It's like if you try to build a dynamic website without a preprocessor.

Comment: Very often unexperienced front-end designers try to approach goals with JS which should be approached in the back-end instead.